# XMR deposit from Monero GUI wallet is not showing up on Poloniex

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-confirmation, payment-integration, third-party-wallets

today I sent 7.42 XMR from my Monero GUI Wallet on my Mac to the Poloniex Exchange. It has been a few hours waiting and the XMR are still not showing up in my Poloniex Wallet. The transaction appears to have completed successfully from looking at the transaction history on the Monero GUI Wallet and the XMR is gone from my Monero GUI Wallet ..any assistance would be most appreciated...

Comment: Hello ..thanks for your reply ..I tried to follow your instructions and the output showed up as 'false". Perhaps I have misinterpreted your instructions. Here are the "Transaction Details" for the Monero Wallet GUI: Tx ID: 6f10b6c5fb74d73dd473d9e30af937e2380ac70a07003052f6a9af55ca06‌​fb23 Payment ID: 0f889fd14319004c Tx key: f4ff9b50a3703445860dfafc34fcb0825515393363fefaa0ddeffb1cc4ca‌​460b Destinations: 7.426813920000: 48mxGC7MjyhWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL‌​2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRw‌​sQvVCjZbHuK7RDn

Comment: Here is the public key from my Poloniex Monero Wallet: 4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL‌​2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRw‌​sQvVCjZbRw5NKMdBAib9‌​cCXgAH

Comment: I am wondering if I have followed the correct procedure ..are you able to confirm? ..any assistance would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I noticed that i missed selecting the "Prove Sending" tab ..I followed the procedure again ..this time the result came up: Cant parse xmr address: 4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL‌​‌​2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAg‌​Rw‌​sQvVCjZbRw5NKMdB‌​Aib9‌​cCXgAH

Comment: I have followed the procedure to the best of my ability ..not sure what to do next ..please help...

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this happens it is probably an issue on Poloniex' end. That is, your deposit has arrived, but isn't credited properly. If you want to check whether the deposit has actually arrived, but is simply not credited yet, you can use the following steps:

1. In the GUI, go to the history page and click on details of the transaction that was sent to Poloniex. | For the CLI, enter the following command: `get_tx_key <transaction_hash>`.
2. A window should pop up that shows the private tx key. Copy it. | For the CLI, copy the outcome of the `get_tx_key` command.
3. Go to [this](https://xmrchain.net) block explorer.
4. Enter your transaction ID / hash.
5. Now search the page for `Prove sending`.
6. Enter the private transaction key you obtained in step 2 into the first box. In addition, enter the integrated address Poloniex provided in the second box.
7. Press on prove sending.
8. If it shows "output true" it proves you correctly sent your XMR to Poloniex, but they haven't credited it yet. It could be that their wallet is temporarily stuck.